# If child aria-expanded=true add class to parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add a class to a parent element if `aria-expanded=true`?

I have the following markup:

```js
$(function () {
      if ($('.navbar-collapse').attr('aria-expanded') === "true") {
        $(this).parents("header").addClass('red');
    }
});
```

```css
.red { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="navbar navbar-s" id="master" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
     <nav id="main-navbar" class="navbar-collapse" role="navigation" aria-expanded="true">
        Navigation
     </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

I think the if-query works but not the other code.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is that `this` within the `if` condition will refer to the `window`, not your selected `.navbar-collapse` element.

To solve this you could use the 'attribute selector' to retrieve the element then chain the required methods calls to add the class to the parent target Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.navbar-collapse[aria-expanded="true"]').closest('header').addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="navbar navbar-s" id="master" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <nav id="main-navbar" class="navbar-collapse" role="navigation" aria-expanded="true">
      Navigation
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` in `if` block doesn't refers to the `nav` element thus your didn't work.

You can use [`Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to target element then traverse up.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.navbar-collapse[aria-expanded="true"]').parents("header").addClass('red');
});
```

```css
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="navbar navbar-s" id="master" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <nav id="main-navbar" class="navbar-collapse" role="navigation" aria-expanded="true">
      Navigation
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```